# Why Git says my branch is up to date and there's nothing to commit?

Tags: git, github, repository, git-branch

Git is not updating the code in the text editor anymore. It seems to be disconnected from the local branch.

For some reason, every change in the code that is saved is not being recognized by Git anymore. It seems that the local branch doesn't know about the remote branch. It supposed to compare. I think Git won't tell the difference between the branch and the remote one

```
RD-MBP-13:testing-123 lucas$ git push origin main
Everything up-to-date
RD-MBP-13:testing-123 lucas$ ls
README.md   style.css   test.html
RD-MBP-13:testing-123 lucas$
```

I've noticed many people are facing this problem. I think people are having a hard time finding a conclusion for this weird issue.

Does anybody know what's causing this and if there's a solution that could save this problem?

Comment: Nothing in your output above shows any problems. What do you think is wrong?

Comment: give us more details: output these commands.

Comment: 1. git status 2. git branch -v 3. git remote -v

Comment: have you commit anything? what other things you tried?

Comment: every change I do in the text editor - test.html file is not updating when I want to commit to the branch in the terminal. The terminal is connected to the branch server but the text editor seems to be disconnected from the terminal. For example, I can create a new style.css in the terminal but this file doesn't show in the text editor. So something stoped the conection

Comment: Double checking: Do you have the same working directory in your editor and terminal? `pwd` in terminal to check.

Comment: In the text editor Atom, I only have two files - README.md and test.html while in terminal Git I have three files README.md test.html and style.css because I created a CSS file to check if the terminal was connected to Github. when I tape pwd it shows this /Users/lucas/testing-123

Comment: I could even push the style.css file to the branch but I can't add code in the text editor. I don't know how to reconnect Git to my text editor again

Comment: This looks more like you've convinced the Atom editor to use a completely different set of files. I know very little about Atom myself, but I'd recommend editing the question's tags to add [tag:atom-editor].